# URL key already exists

Tags: magento2, category, error, category-products, url-key

[image]

When category is edit, The Magento shows this message error.

Comment: this mean you already have a same url_key.. So try to find that one and change it otherwise give some other url_key for this one

Comment: @AsishHira does magento2 have a url rewrite section like 1? I cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

for URL Rewrite Go to Magento admin
In the Left-hand menu section click **Marketing** >> **SEO & Search** >> **URL Rewrites**

Click **edit** for changing desired URL rewrite

Change URL accordingly and execute indexing command

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**